# Vue3 trigger event from another window

Tags: passport-google-oauth

**Background:**
I have a `Nuxt` front-end and `Nestjs` API. I would like to integrate OAuth2 with Google using `passport-js`.

**Userflow:**

1. You are somewhere on the website.
2. You click `Sign in with Google` button and a new window pops up to authenticate with Google.
3. After authentication you are redirected back to the website, but not to the page where you were, but to `/login/success?jwt=[generated jwt]`.
4. You see `Login successful` message, the jwt is extracted and saved to the `localStorage`. The window is automatically closed after 2 seconds.
5. You still have your old window opened at the proper location, but you do not see you are logged in.

**Question:**
Is it possible to trigger an event from the popup, which would check the localStorage in the main window to get the new login status? Or maybe there is a more straight-forward solution for this?